# Google Cloud App Engine Website - unable to access on VPN

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, web-hosting

I have hosted a website using google cloud app engine. However, I am not able to access the website when I am connected through a VPN.

Are there any security settings on cloud to enable this?

I appreciate the leads here.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a route to the public Internet? What error are you getting.? Does the DNS name resolve? More details are required.

Comment: DNS resolves the name. I am able to access without a VPN connection.     
error on browser: SECURITY THREAT DETECTED AND BLOCKED

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if you are using App Engine standard, you are not able to access it through VPN directly. There are two option to achieve it:

The first one is to use a feature called App Engine Flexible. This solution is base on define the network settings when you perform the deployment on your app.yaml configuration file. For more information about it please review [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible).

The second option is to use Serverless VPC Access, but there is a little bit more complex, let me explain why. When you use it this feature, You are establishing connection between your App Engine app directly to Compute Engine VM instances.

So you will need to establish first a VPN in order to reach your VM instance, for more details please check [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-static-vpns). And then establish connection [VM->App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/connecting-vpc). And then configure [VPC Serverless Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access).

I hope all this information could help you to achieve your goal.